# Adding one model to another rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm trying to come up with a way to let a customer add themselves to a category. Meaning - I want to be able to call in my views @customer.add_to_category(category), or similar. Any suggestions?

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
#Associations


has_many :customers

#Defs
def add_customer(customer_id)
    current_customer = Customer.find_by(customer_id: customer_id)
    if current_customer
        current_customer = Customer.build(customer_id: customer_id) 
    end
    current_customer
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current schema, each category can only belong to one user.  It would be better to have it like so:

```
Customer
  has_many :customer_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :customer_categories

Category
  has_many :customer_categories
  has_many :customers, :through => :customer_categories  

CustomerCategory
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :category
```

Then your Category#add_customer method should just be

```
def add_customer(customer_id)
  if customer = Customer.where(id: customer_id).first
    self.customers << customer unless self.customers.include?(customer)
  end
end
```

You could do the converse of this in the Customer class, obviously.

Comment: You'll need the table too.

Comment: Yep, as @japed reminds me, it's a general rule that when you change your schema you may well need a migration to go along with it, to add the necessary tables/columns.

Comment: That was actually as liroy had asked whether he'd need the table too in a comment, which seems to have gone now.